# Inverse probability weighted Kaplan-Meier for left truncated data

Tags: r, survival, kaplan-meier, survey-weights

Is there any R implementation of inverse probability weighted Kaplan-Meier estimator for left truncated and right censored data?

I found only implementation without left truncation in *IPWsurvival* package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How I can understand that survfit() I used is considering left-truncation?

Comment: Hello! 
In my opinion, you can see this by printing a Surv() object. If it looks like [200, 269+], then the left truncation is used. If it looks like  269+ – then the left truncation is not used.

Answer (score 2):

God, that was incredibly easy.

This can obviously be done with a conventional function *survfit()*. You need to assign desired weights to parameter *w*. Package *IPWsurvival* is needed only for the correct application of logrank test.

I hope this answer will save a lot of time for future researchers.